# Is it possible to save a verifiable log of a TLS session?

Tags: tls, digital-signature

Here's an example situation:

I download a file from some server over https, but I also save a "log" of the TLS communication. Later, that file is removed from the server and nobody believes me when I say that the server had once hosted that file. However, the "log" that I saved is verifiable proof that I had obtained the file from the server in question.

I put the word "log" in quotes because I'm not even sure if such a thing is possible. Is it?

Comment: In court, printed web pages are usually considered as proof, because it's something everyone can understand. Not sure what's the purpose of technically solid proof of existence.

Comment: Also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187577/can-you-use-https-to-prove-document-was-sent-from-domain